# Is it possible to Enable full screen exclusive mode if isDisplayChangeSupported() shows its not available

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm new to java Game development.
Please let me know if its possible to Enable full screen exclusive mode if isDisplayChangeSupported() shows its not available.

about isDisplayChangeSupported() : By getting GraphicalEnvironment() we can perform many modifications in the graphics and change the display mode(like getting full access of the full-screen).
We use isDisplayChangeSupported() to verify if the written displaymode changes is getting applied or not, by simply checking does the system supports changes in Display mode.

If its possible to enable it then please tell me how.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two entirely different features:

1. [Full Screen Window](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow(java.awt.Window))

   Setting a full screen window *always* works. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow(java.awt.Window)) says:

   > The entered full-screen mode may be either exclusive or simulated. Exclusive mode is only available if `isFullScreenSupported` returns `true`.

   So when [`isFullScreenSupported`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isFullScreenSupported()) returns `false`, it still works but is simulated.
2. [Display mode changes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setDisplayMode(java.awt.DisplayMode))

   are about changing the resolution and/or color depth of the screen. They may require setting a full screen window first, as a prerequisite, but when display mode changes are not supported, full screen window still works:

   > Sets the display mode of this graphics device. This is only allowed if [`isDisplayChangeSupported()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isDisplayChangeSupported()) returns true and may require first entering full-screen exclusive mode using [`setFullScreenWindow(java.awt.Window)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#setFullScreenWindow(java.awt.Window)) providing that full-screen exclusive mode is supported (i.e., [`isFullScreenSupported()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#isFullScreenSupported()) returns true).